# How to create an input field, and base the output on spreadsheet data?

Tags: plugins, functions, custom-field, css

Fair warning, I'm brand-new to WordPress.

I'm creating a site about fonts. I'm trying to set it up so that the user enters a font name in an input field on the home page, presses a "Submit" button, and a "results" page loads showing complimentary fonts to the one they searched for.

I have all the font info ready in an excel spreadsheet, but I don't know how to create the input-output system. I'm not even sure what kinds of tutorials I should be searching for on YouTube. Does this type of function have a more accurate name? If there a plugin I should be looking for? I'm willing to learn how to code some CSS if needed, I just need a little help!

Comment: You need to code PHP to do this. CSS is not going to cut it.   Yuo want a html form in a wordpress page that dynamically fetches data from either a file or the DB.  DB will be easier I think, so you'lll need to work out how best to store the relationship  of fonts (Can you use std wordpress structures or do you need a custom table?)  To learn:  google & read up on 1) writing a plugin to create a shortcode https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API  (2) cteate a form and an action in response to the form  3) use wpdb to select from the db.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb